# Question on the proof of a weak convergence result of signed measures in a book of Bogachev

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence, signed-measures

Please consider the following basic result on the weak convergence of nets of radon measures, which can be found in a [book of Bogachev](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/surv-234):

[image]

I wonder whether I'm missing something, but I don't get why he claims that the integrals of $f$ and $g$ with respect to $\mu_\alpha$ differ by less than $3\varepsilon$ and the integrals of $f$ with respect to $\mu_\alpha$ and $\mu$ differ by less than $7\varepsilon$.

It's clearly not important for the result, but I've got the strange feeling that I'm missing something.

Shouldn't we have \begin{equation}\begin{split}\left|(\mu_\alpha-\mu)(f-g)\right|&\le\underbrace{\int_K\underbrace{|f-g|}_{<\:\varepsilon}\:{\rm d}|\mu_\alpha-\mu|}_{\le\:\varepsilon(\left\|\mu_\alpha\right\|+\left\|\mu\right\|)\:\le\:2\varepsilon}\\&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;+\underbrace{\int_{K^c}\underbrace{|f-g|}_{\le\:2}\:{\rm d}|\mu_\alpha-\mu|}_{\le\:2(|\mu_\alpha|+|\mu|)(K^c)\:<\:2\varepsilon}<4\varepsilon\end{split}\tag1\end{equation} and hence $$|(\mu_\alpha-\mu)f|\le|(\mu_\alpha-\mu)(f-g)|+|(\mu_\alpha-\mu)g|<5\varepsilon?\tag2$$

BTW, do we really need to assume that the $\mu_\alpha$ are Radon? I think this is redundant by the uniform tightness assumption. It's only important that $\{\mu\}$ is tight as well in order to ensure the existence of $K$ (which is clearly the case when $\mu$ is Radon).

---

[image]

Comment: "... the integrals ... with respect to the measures $\mu_{\alpha}$ differ by less than $3\varepsilon$". So $\int_K \lvert f-g\rvert\,d\lvert\mu_{\alpha}\rvert < \varepsilon$ and $\int_{K^c} \lvert f-g\rvert\, d\lvert \mu_{\alpha}\rvert < 2\varepsilon$ sum to a bound of $3\varepsilon$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Right, but why does he end up with $7\varepsilon$. Yes, most probably by having the same bound of $3\varepsilon$ for $\mu$ in place of $\mu_\alpha$, but is anything wrong with what I've done $(1)$? It should yield a bound by $5\varepsilon$ at the end. I'm just curious whether I've missed something important, but maybe he simply used that $|\mu_\alpha|(K^c),|\mu|(K^c)<\varepsilon$ separately, whereas I've used that even their sum is $<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Yes, "The same is also true for $\mu$." gives $2\cdot 3\varepsilon$; plus one for $(\mu - \mu_{\alpha})(g)$ makes $7$. And yes, estimating your way gives a smaller constant factor. But who cares, a factor of $2^{2^{100}}$ would also work. (That's not to say it's useless to do the estimate in a way that seems natural to you. It's only pointless, but also harmless fun, so nothing wrong with it, if you do it only to reduce the constant.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Sure, I just thought I would miss something crucial. Can you say something about the Radon assumption on $\mu_\alpha$?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. (And even if I were to think about it, it may depend on the definition of Radon measure, iirc there are different ones.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Added the definition. I think we only need that $\{\mu_\alpha\}\cup\{\mu\}$ is tight. But besides that assumption, $\mu_\alpha,\mu$ can be arbitrary finite signed measures.

Comment: A tight measure on a metric space is automatically Radon.  Every Borel measure on a metric space is regular (Bogachev Theorem 1.4.8, which as pointed out in Theorem 7.1.7 is valid in any metric space, not just $\mathbb{R}^n$ as it is stated), and a tight regular measure is Radon.  So the assumption is technically redundant but also harmless, and in my opinion it makes the statement clearer.